# TFS Work Items query to find tasks NOT included in release

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, tfs

I am no TFS expert, but I use it regularly to work on tasks and I have created a couple custom queries in the Work Items section.  Someone else handles deployments and they sometimes miss a task that was not associated with a Release.

So, I would like to create a custom query that returns tasks that are not "Included In Release", and by Project.  I can't seem to find the right field(s) to filter on, or I am not filtering properly.  So far, I have a clause for Project:

```
[And/Or]    [Field]    [Operator]    [Value]
            Project        =       project name
```

And a clause for:

```
[And/Or]    [Field]        [Operator]     [Value]
  And     Work Item Type       =       Release Package
```

but that returns only items of Release Package work item type.

I think tasks are associated or linked to a release package work item, but don't know how to query on that.

Thx in advance.

BTW, this is my favorite custom TFS query:

```
[And/Or]     [Field]        [Operator]     [Value]
           Assigned To       Was Ever       @Me
```

As you may have guessed, this TFS query will return all items that were ever assigned to me.

UPDATE:
This page has helped a lot:  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/using-queries

Using the dropdown at top next to the Run button, I changed to "Work Items and Direct Links".  This makes available a new section to "Filter for linked work items".  And this is what I have built:

[image: TFS Query - Tasks not Included in Release]

Comment: What's the work item task included in release? Could you show a sample?

Comment: I may have found a solution.  I will update the question.

Comment: @Kershaw does this work for you now? This looks like what you want.

Comment: I am hoping to hear back from our dev mgr, but I think it is what I (he) was after.