# TFS 2017 Work item query for specific release

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem

Is there any way to query work items that are part of a specific Release?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't the way to achieve that with query. You can try to build a extension to get work items of specific release.

Check this thread: [TFS 2017 Release Management: How to display parent PBI for Tasks under Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934425/tfs-2017-release-management-how-to-display-parent-pbi-for-tasks-under-release)

Answer (score 0):

It can't be achieved by creating a basic query, we can see all the associated work items in release Work Items tab.

You can also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40184957/tfs-work-items-query-to-find-tasks-not-included-in-release) may be inspired

[image]

Comment: I know that this possibility exists but the problem is that the user needs to query the tasks and their parent PBI in order to do reporting. I investigated how to create a query for this purpose but I couldn't find a filtering option based on specific release.

Comment: Actually you can add tags that can identify specific releases for each work item during the developing, then you can filter them by a query with the tag. Currently there are no official process to customize the qurey,you can submit an uservoice similar as [customize "search work items" query](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/5433452-customize-search-work-items-query) here.

Comment: Using tags is not a possibility as the tag fields is already used for another purpose. I ended up building an extension that displays the work items with details that I need as starain-MSFT suggested.